# Kryo out of memory

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

No matter what I tried, I get this OOME using Spark 1.3.1 when using Kryo serializer (I don't have any issues if I use the default Java one)

```
15/06/25 20:16:37 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 47.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 59, ip-172-31-28-175.ec2.internal): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.ChunkEncoder.encodeAndWriteChunk(ChunkEncoder.java:264)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFOutputStream.writeCompressedBlock(LZFOutputStream.java:266)
        at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFOutputStream.write(LZFOutputStream.java:124)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:155)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:31)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:27)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:27)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:21)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:29)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:27)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:27)
        at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:21)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:110)
```

I have 40GB of RAM available on both the driver and the executors. I tried playing with Kryo buffer size / max size (increased from the default all the way to ridiculous values), but to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong? Is that a know issue? Is there a solution?

**EDIT** tried with 1.4.0 same issue.

p.s. this only happens on the cluster. Locally I'm getting it to work successfully.

In summary

1. Locally it works with or without Kryo Serializer (smaller data set though), with 1.3.1 and 1.4.0
2. On the cluster it works with the default Java serializer, but fails on 1.3.1 and 1.4.0 using the Kryo serializer with the same error message.

Comment: Did you ever discover the cause of these OOM errors?

Comment: No, but I think it disappeared with Spark 1.5.x

Answer (score 0):

This error is a bit of a misnomer. This does not mean your machine does not have enough memory, it means that Kryo was trying to create a byte array with a more than (2^31 -1) elements.

This is probably happening because your Spark tasks are quite large. If You have written your Spark job in Scala you may be accidentally pulling extra objects into scope and bloating your job size. What do I mean by that?

1. When you create a lambda function to by used by Spark, Spark looks at all the objects that are referred to by the lambda function
2. Spark then serializes them and bundles them with the Task definition. So if you are accessing large data structures, outside classes, or global variables from your lambda functions you can easily quickly bloat your Task definitions to the point where they are larger than (2^31 - 1) bytes.
3. Then when Kryo will try to make a byte array larger than (2^31 - 1) and the OutOfMemoryException you've seen will be thrown.